# self updating air application assets without re-downloading assets already downloaded

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

I want an air application to be able to update the assets it uses, but minimizing the download needed, so only downloading files added since it last updated.

I'm thinking this would include a server portion which would zip the needed files based on a version number? Has anyone implemented anything similar / got any thoughts on the best approach to building this sort of system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you said works.

You could also have it download an index of assets, figure out which aren't there (or changed based on a size or hash), and download those.  That sounds simpler to me than a combined server/client solution.